# fr:number control with a suffix not editable after becoming relevant

Tags: orbeon

I am using an `fr:number` control with a suffix.

It is relevant at the time the form is displayed and is editable.
On clicking (un-ticking) a tick box, the control is hidden according to custom XPath.

However, when the the tick box is re-ticked, the control reappears but on attempting to edit the text it is readonly.

This behaviour is only apparent in IE (IE11) and when the control has a suffix.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: I don't think that this is a known bug. Which exact version of Orbeon Forms are you using?

Comment: Also, if you're not using Orbeon Forms 2017.1, would you be able to check if the problem also happens with that version?

Comment: This would be in Orbeon 2016.2